# remove input in add new input with jQuery. how is fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can putting link add after last new input when click on remove no after last input that clicked on remove. how is it?

when you clicked on remove(no last remove) you see that link add append after input. Namely we have tow or several add link after clicked on  remove. you in anywhere clicked on remove append link add on input, i want only once append in last new input no in anywhere.
I hope you understand

**EXAMPLE:**  http://jsfiddle.net/zgWr3/12/

```
$('a.remove_input').live('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var $class =  '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');
                $(this).closest($class).prev().find('.adda .mediumCell').append('<a href="" class="add_input"></a>')
                $(this).closest($class).remove();
            });
```

With respect

Comment: I'm really sorry, I tried for some time to understand what you are trying to do now. You want to add an input on every click, right? All of these newly added inputs should have a link to remove them, but there should only be one add button? Did I get that right?

Comment: yes, add button only for last new input and remove button for all except first input. but in my code `$('a.remove_input')` have problem!!!

Comment: okay. Looking at your code, I think you are approaching this problem a little too complicated. If you only have one add button, why do you even want to add a new one with javascript? Let the existing one stay there and only add the remove-buttons with functionality. I'll try it in a jsFiddle and show you

Answer (score 1):

For my HTML I would use something like:

```
<div id="inputs">
    <div id="input_container_0">
        <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="hello" />
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="Javascript:void(0);" class="action-add">add</a>
</div>
```

For my JavaScript I would use something like:

```
var number_of_inputs = 0;
$(function() {
    $(".action-add").click(function() {
        number_of_inputs++;
        $("#inputs").append('<div id="input_container_'+number_of_inputs.toString()+'"><input type="text" name="price" placeholder="hello" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="Javascript:void(0);" rel="'+number_of_inputs.toString()+'" class="action-remove">remove</a></div>');
    });
    $(".action-remove").live('click', function() {
        $("#input_container_"+$(this).attr("rel")).remove();
    });
});
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

Updated, so the remove link is not present for the first text box.

Comment: I do not use of a HTML code. i have used several different HTML they in a changing

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The HTML for the inputs are always changing?

Answer (score 0):

Here. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {

        var $column = $(this).closest('div.add_units');

        // clone the top input row
        var newDiv = $($column.find('div.mediumCell').get(0)).clone(true);
        // clear field values
        newDiv.find('input').val(''); // clear the field

        // add Remove link to new row
        newDiv.append('<a href="#" class="remove_input">remove</a>');

        $column.find('div.adda').before(newDiv);

        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $('a.remove_input').live('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // find row
        $row = $(this).closest('.mediumCell').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: wow, this gives me a lot of remove-links, can you post the jsFiddle-Link?

Comment: I do not use of a HTML code. i have used several different HTML they in a changing